# Is there a relay to digitally check if mains is available

Tags: digital-logic

I am working on a system that will remotely turn on/off an appliance (RaspberryPi running a web server, sending input to a relay). One problem that I still need to get sorted is that, how can I check if the electricity is available. Is there some kind of a relay (or other component) that I can use to tell my RaspberryPi that electricity is available for the appliance to be turned on/off.

Comment: How are you planning to power the Pi if there is no electricity?

Comment: The Pi will be connected to a UPS, the appliance that I want to switch on/off won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's many ways to do this, some more dangerous than the others. How about just taking a 3 volt wall DC supply and connecting the output to your Raspi? When there's power available, the output will be at 3 volts. And when not, it will be at zero.

Comment: Although not exactly the question that I asked but this does sound an interesting(and safer) idea, that I am going to adopt. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use a mains relay and use a contact of it to indicate that mains is present.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXLSt5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Mains present indication. Enable the GPIO pin internal pull-up resistor.*

There are other ways using opto-isolators, etc., but since you are already using relays it makes sense to use another. The isolated or "volt-free" contact provides isolation to prevent mains getting near your Pi. The relay coil should be AC type with voltage selected to suit your mains voltage.

Comment: And look for an AC relay that draws very low current. There are differences and if the relay is going to be continuously connected to the AC mains, it would help a little to use as low a current as economically feasible, consistent with availability too.

Comment: @Omer: (1) How far from the Pi to the load switching relay? (This may affect my answer.) (2) What cable will connect them? Number of cores?

Comment: @Transistor its in the same room, the distance between the Pi and the relay is ~5 meters. Currently I have been using the commonly found jumper cables.

Comment: That should be fine then. It might be a good idea to add 100 nF between the GPIO and GND to reduce susceptibility to noise.

Answer (score 1):

These are called "27" relays because the ANSI function number for loss of voltage is 27.  Any standard relay should work, just match the coil voltage to the voltage you are working with as transistor stated.  You will not have to worry to much about the specs for the contact on the relay as this will be feeding an input to your GPIO pin on the Pi, so will be 3.3V at very low current.  However, to separate the GPIO pin and the mains power you will want the contact to be "dry", meaning you need to supply it with voltage.  So I think the circuit diagram in transistor's answer should look like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftOhKn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A link to a common relay here in the midwest is:
[A-B relay](http://raise.rockwellautomation.com/RAConfig/resultsComponents.asp?CID=F4EB3EEC68EC4394AAAF07336CA1E4EB)

You can probably find cheaper relays, but this is similar to what I think you would want.  Of course, you will have to match the type of relay for your installation, i.e., flange, socket, panel mount, etc. but this is just to give you an idea.  Note, I used what's called a form "C" relay, meaning you have normally open and normally closed contacts - if voltage is good, the normally open contact will close and the normally closed contact will open.  That way you can wire it up whichever way you want (good mains voltage provides a high signal at the Pi, wire to the normally open contact; good voltage provides a low signal at the Pi, wire to the normally closed contact.)

As transistor also stated, you will need to configure the pin as an input and make sure you have the right pull-ups configured.

Comment: You'll need a pull-down for your circuit schematic - not a pull-up as mentioned in the last paragraph. (I know you know this but your readers may not.)